# Angular Show HTML response data into view

Tags: javascript, angular6

Hello i am new to angular and i can not figure it out to show html response data in component below is my code please someone help with this.
Thanks

**data.Service.ts** (here i call an API service which return some html)

```
getLibrary() {return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/user/library');}
```

**Library.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-library',
  templateUrl: './library.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./library.component.scss']
})
export class LibraryComponent implements OnInit {

  library: any;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getLibrary().subscribe(
      data => this.library = data 

    );



  }

}
```

**Library.component.html**

```
{{library}}
```

**Error**

```
core.js:14576 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8000/api/user/library", ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttp…, text: "<div style="display:block" class="libContainer lib…            
↵           </div>
↵
↵
↵</div>
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8000/api/user/library"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8000/api/user/library"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Comment: what does the response look like? please add to code. not looking like a JSON response

Comment: response is HTML only no JSON

Comment: response is like => <h1>Some Html Content</h1>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

returned datatype is text you can use like this

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.data.getLibrary().subscribe(
          (data:(any)) => this.library = data 

        );
```

in view

```
<div [innerHTML]="library"></div>
```

Comment: yes now html is rendered on view after using  json_encode(); but not rendering as HTMl its rendering as text on view

Comment: in view use <div [innerHTML]="library"></div>

Comment: Thank u so much its working now..have a great day :)